Schwinger approach using the heat kernel
I am having trouble calculating the effective action for a constant magnetic background. The calculations I am trying to replicate are from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807031. The effective action is given by
$$\mathrm{S}_{\text {eff }}=-\frac{i}{2} \operatorname{tr} \ln \left(\not D^2+m^2\right)=\frac{i}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d s}{s} \operatorname{tr} e^{-s\left(\not D^2+m^2\right)}\tag{7}$$
where
$$\not D^2+m^2=\left[\partial_0^2-\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2-\left(\partial_z+i B y\right)^2+m^2\right] \mathbf{1}+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}B & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -B & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & B & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -B\end{array}\right).\tag{8}$$
And so the eigenvalues are $$m^2-k_0^2+k_x^2+2 B\left(n+\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}\right).\tag{9}$$ I don't see how tracing with these eigenvalues gives,
$$\mathrm{S}_{\text {eff }}=\frac{BTL^{3}}{ 8\pi^{2}}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d s}{s^{2}} e^{-s m^{2}}\text{coth}(Bs) + \text{renormalization}.\tag{10}$$
My calculations read,
$$\mathrm{S}_{\text {eff }}=\frac{iL^{3}}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d s}{s} e^{-s m^{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dk_{0}dk_{x}}{(2\pi)^{2}}e^{sk_{0}^{2}}e^{-
sk_{x}^{2}}\int_{0}^{BT}\frac{dk_{z}}{2\pi}\sum_{\pm}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-2 Bs (n+\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2})s}$$
which simplifies to
$$\mathrm{S}_{\text {eff }}=\frac{BTL^{3}}{16\pi^{2}}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d s}{s^{2}} e^{-s m^{2}}\coth(Bs) + \text{renormalization}$$
This differs by a factor of 2 from the result in the paper.
